# Identify and Calculate Free Area in Vanning Slot Image Using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project where I need to identify and calculate the free area within a vanning slot in a warehouse. The vanning slot is marked with yellow color, and there are pallets occupying some of the space within this yellow-marked area.

I have already implemented a Python code using OpenCV to isolate the yellow color and extract the gray area covered by the yellow lines. The code is provided below:

```
    from PIL import Image
    from IPython.display import display

    # Replace 'your_image_path.jpg' with the actual path to your image file
    image_path = 'C:/Users/CSR/Desktop/tracking_images/Half Vanning.jpg'

    # Open the image file
    img = Image.open(image_path)

    # Display the image
    display(img)

    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image
    from IPython.display import display



    # Load the image
    image_path = 'C:/Users/CSR/Desktop/tracking_images/Half Vanning.jpg' 
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Define the lower and upper bounds for the yellow color in HSV
    lower_yellow = np.array([20, 100, 100], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_yellow = np.array([40, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)

    # Convert the image to HSV color space
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Create a binary mask for the yellow color
    yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)

    # Apply a bitwise AND operation to extract the gray area covered by yellow lines
    gray_area = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask=yellow_mask)

    # Save the result
    output_path = 'C:/Users/CSR/Desktop/04-08-2023/bz.jpg'  # Change this to the desired output path
    cv2.imwrite(output_path, gray_area)

    print("Result image saved to:", output_path)

    # Open the image file
    img = Image.open(output_path)

    # Display the image
    display(img)
```

input image:

[image: input image]

My output image:

[image: My output image]

However, I am struggling to determine the free area within this yellow-marked vanning slot – the area not occupied by pallets. I would like to calculate and visualize this free space. Could you please provide guidance on how to achieve this? Specifically, how can I identify and calculate the unoccupied (free) area within the yellow-marked vanning slot?

Sample image:

[image: sample image]

Expected output:

![expected output][2]

[output_image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41GYf.jpg)
[output_image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l33aH.jpg)

Comment: After finding the yellow lines, you're going to need quite a different algorithm to check that the region is free. Variations in lighting, ground color, etc., as well as the unpredictability of the clutter that could occupy the space suggest a different approach. If there's any chance you could use a long-range 3D sensor that could help, BUT accuracy at that distance will be poor. For long-term robustness this is a hard problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend u some pseudo code steps:

- use color filter for the image, as u did
- do contour detect
- filter contours for min sizes, to cut out noise ( quite sensitive treshold)
- merge rest contours
- to a convex hull to surround all rest contours (obj named hull)

Me suggest steps in code:

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display

# Get Path to current working directory
cwd = os.getcwd()

# Load the image
image_path = os.path.join(cwd ,"eFCrs.jpg")

#check file exists
if not os.path.isfile(image_path):
    print("File", image_path, "doesn't exist")
    exit()

image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply a Gaussian blur with a 5x5 kernel to reduce noise
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Define the lower and upper bounds for the yellow color in HSV
lower_yellow = np.array([20, 100, 100], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_yellow = np.array([40, 255, 255], dtype=np.uint8)

# Convert the image to HSV color space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Create a binary mask for the yellow color
yellow_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)

# Apply a bitwise AND operation to extract the gray area covered by yellow lines
gray_area = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask=yellow_mask)

# we do a contour detect to find the yellow lines
# Find the contours of the gray area
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray_area, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Define a max area size to filter out small contours
# Filter the contours by area and resize to the original size
minAreaSizeAllowed = 400 #quite sensitive 
contours = [cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 3, True) for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) > minAreaSizeAllowed]

# Draw all the contours on a copy of the original image for debug
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# We merge all other contours into via corner points
# Merge all the contours into one
surronding_contours = np.concatenate(contours)

# Compute the convex hull of the biggest contour
hull = cv2.convexHull(surronding_contours)

# draw the convex hull on the original image in blue color, this is the free space
cv2.drawContours(image, [hull], -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)

# Add red Rectangle around the convex hull
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(hull)
cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 3)

# Save the result
output_path = os.path.join(cwd,'outfoo.jpg')  # Change this to the desired output path
cv2.imwrite(output_path, image)
print("Result image saved to:", output_path)

# Open the image file
img = Image.open(output_path)

# Display the image
display(img)
```

output is: [image: outfoo.jpg]

Comment: Suppose the pallets are arranged in a zigzag position or whatever, meaning they occupy the yellow-colored vanning slots in various dimensions. The desired output should display only the remaining free space within the vanning slots?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar If there are other possibilities for the way the scene looks which mean this code doesn't work, please provide counter-examples of such images in your question. Thank you.

Comment: i added the image in my question part.

Comment: image name which i mentioned above is "sample image"

Comment: in this "sample image" i need to calculate free area of the vanning slot

Comment: i mentioned expected output also. please help me

Comment: actually i do think the solution is already in my answer,  hull  is the polygon including the free area

Comment: Can we fill the free space with blue color?

Comment: in your output, the free space polygon area is slightly different. so please help me

Comment: i need exact area . that is why i am asking u "Can we fill the free space with blue color?"

Comment: so we can easily find only blue color area (free space area).